# REG DELETE one value instead of the whole key

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I am writing a script to delete all registry keys with the value Vipre. For most this is really easy and I can just add them like this:

```
REG DELETE "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\Interface\{B3566D12-5895-4511-ADB2-125BFF23891E}" /f
```

But I have now ran into the issue of needing to delete just one value within a folder without deleting the whole registry folder.

In the case I am currently asking about the folder is:

```
REG DELETE "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Folders" /f
```

Within this folder there is a value of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vipre`

This is the only portion of the folder I want deleted. The rest of the folder contains a lot of other keys I DON'T want deleted. How do I add the individual key to the delete command so I only delete the particular key?

Comment: Quick terminology lesson: What you're calling "folders" in regedit are known in the Windows Registry APIs as *keys*.  And the entries inside the folders are called *values*, each of which has a *name* and *data*

Comment: Thank you very much for the lesson. I'm having a new problem. I basically scrapped what I was doing in my question and have gone to this method:     wmic product where name="VIPRE Business Agent" call uninstall    but while it looks like its working Vipre isn't actually uninstalling

Comment: For that you should probably [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include a new problem. Instead, create a new question.

Comment: @Matt I tried to delete this question since that is exactly what I wanted to do, but since there is already an answer I can't. I have already asked this question in a new question and flagged this one for deletion.

Comment: @EddieStuder: Why do you need to delete this question to ask a new question? You can leave this one be, but still ask a new question.

Comment: @Matt I just thought that if this question had changed so much it would need to be deleted to make sure there wasn't any confusion.

Comment: @EddieStuder: Even though your problem might have changed, this question (as a question "How do I add the individual key to the delete command so I only delete the particular key?") is still valid, still has an answer, and can still (in its current form) prove useful to a future user who needs to do the same thing. As your problem evolves, it is preferable on Stack Overflow to ask new questions, rather than re-writing your existing ones (where each re-write invalidates any answers that might have been posted on the question). I don't see why deleting this question will avoid any confusion?

Comment: @matt Ok I will take this approach in the future with my questions. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use the `/v` flag to specify just one value to delete.

```
REG DELETE "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Folders" /v "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vipre"
```

Note that the argument to `/v` needs to be the *name* of the entry you want to delete, and not its *data* value.

See `REG DELETE /?` for more details.